# Why does an allocator interface-encapsulating nested class of a "list" implementation benefit from also encapsulating a node?

Tags: c++, list, optimization

In [The "Empty Member" C++ Optimization](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html) is the following code snippet:

```
// Listing 4: A Better Way to Eliminate Bloat

template <class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> >
class list {
  . . .
  struct Node { . . . };
  struct P : public Alloc {
    P(Alloc const& a) : Alloc(a), p(0) { }
    Node* p; // Why also encapsulate a Node pointer?
  };
  P head_;

 public:
  explicit list(Alloc const& a = Alloc())
    : head_(a) { . . . }
  . . .
};
```

The purpose of this implementation is primarily to avoid object bloat in case the `Alloc` class has no data members (as in the default `allocator` class), but an important noted benefit of this particular implementation is to prevent potential name conflicts between the (arbitrary) `Alloc` class and the members of the `list` class.

A comment beneath the code snippet summarizes this by stating the following:

> Now, list<> members get storage by saying "head_.allocate()", and
>   mention the first list element by saying "head_.p". This works
>   perfectly, there's no unnecessary overhead of any kind, and users of
>   list<> can't tell the difference.

I understand the first part of this comment, namely, the interface encapsulation within the `P` class so that `list<>` members must call `head_.allocate()` to obtain storage.

However, I do not understand the second part of this comment - why it is necessary (or beneficial) to include a `Node` pointer in class `P` so that `list<>` members mention the first list element by saying `head_.p` (rather than just having `p` be a member of `list<>` directly)?  Is this related to encapsulating the interface of the `Alloc` class?

Why does the interface-encapsulating nested class have a pointer to a `Node`, rather than the top-level class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `sizeof(list)` will be `sizeof(P)`, which in turn is, hopefully, `sizeof(Node*)`. If the `Alloc` type is empty, its space usage will be optimised away.

Now consider then the following alternative.

```
class list {
  struct Node { . . . };
  struct P : public Alloc {
    P(Alloc const& a) : Alloc(a), p(0) { }
  };
  Node* head_pointer;
  P thing_with_allocator;
}
```

In this case, `sizeof(list)` will be `sizeof(Node*) + sizeof(P)`. The empty base class optimisation cannot really help here, because, even if `P` is now an empty class, it is not used as a base, so it cannot be subject to the empty base class optimisation: its size is at least 1.

Answer (score 1):

What would your alternative be?

```
class list {
    struct P : public Alloc {
        P(Alloc const& a) : Alloc(a), p(0) { }
    };
    P a;
    Node* h;
    ...
};
```

Then you wouldn't have saved anything because you've had to instantiate a potentially zero sized `P` object. That will take up at least one byte in your list object.